# Simple C code prints nothing to terminal

Tags: c, printing, terminal

I ran a 4 line code and it compiled and linked without a hitch, but it refuses to print anything

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
    char* a = "book";
    printf("%s\n", a);
    return 0;
}
```

After compiling it and running the executable, nothing happens.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the (edited) code. Your console window is opening and closing before you can see the output. Add `getchar()` before `return 0;` to give you a chance to see the output.

Comment: Yes there is nothing wrong.Try weather Vane solution.

Comment: Is it printing to the command line?

Answer (score 0):

No error in the code. 
Just write **getch(); or getchar()** before return 0; 
to holding the output screen.

**getch() or getchar()** will hold the ouput screen for getting the user's input.

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me.

You've tagged this with [terminal](/questions/tagged/terminal); if you are running it from the terminal, you should see some output, in my experience.

If you are running from an IDE,

- keep the window open using [Kapil K.'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50081599);
- keep the window open using an IDE setting, if there is one; or
- find out where your IDE is putting the executable file, and run that from a terminal.